# 2 processing code , one message appear

Tags: java

i start learning Java few weeks ago and i have an assignment to create a button when you click on it you will be asked to enter year 1 ,moth 1, day 1, year 2, moth 2, day 2, and it compares between this two dates to tell you which one is bigger
i write this code and its perfect to me .. P.s i'm using netbeans

```
String s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Year 1");
String s2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Month 1");
String s3=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Day 1");
String s4=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Year 2");
String s5=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Month 2");
String s6=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Day 2");
double y1=Double.parseDouble(s);
double m1=Double.parseDouble(s2);
double d1=Double.parseDouble(s3);
double y2=Double.parseDouble(s4);
double m2=Double.parseDouble(s5);
double d2=Double.parseDouble(s6);
if(y1>y2)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Date1 > Date2");
else if(y1<y2) 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Date1 < Date2");
else if(y1==y2&&m1>m2)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Date1 > Date2");
else if(y1==y2&&m1<m2)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Date1 < Date2");
else if(y1==y2&&m1==m2&&d1>d2)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Date1 > Date2");
else if(y1==y2&&m1==m2&&d1<d2)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Date1 < Date2");
else if(y1==y2&&m1==m2&&d1==d2)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Date1 equal Date2");
```

now i need to make this code more smart so i wrote another code , if someone write 13 for the month 1 for example .. a message will appear says its invalid date and here's the code

```
if (d1<1||d1>31||m1<1||m1>12)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Date 1");
else if(m1==2&&d1>29)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Date 1");
else if((m1==4||m1==6||m1==9||m1==11)&&d1>30)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Date 1");
else if (d2<1||d2>31||m2<1||m2>12)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Date 2");
else if(m2==2&&d2>29)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Date 2");
else if((m2==4||m2==6||m2==9||m2==11)&&d2>30)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Date 2");
```

my problem is when the user write a two dates like
20-13-2005/20-10-2005
my two codes responds together .. it tells him "date 1 > date 2" and an "invalid date" at the same time
my question is how to merge the second code to the first so when the user write an invalid date, the date compare code stop working and only message with invalid date appears ?

sorry i took you so long to read this but i really need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just add a boolean that flags if the date is invalid.  Then you surround the block of code that compares valid dates within an if() block that will only run if the boolean is true.  e.g.,

```
boolean isValid = true;
//code checking for date validity goes here, set isValid to false when validity check fails
if (d1<1||d1>31||m1<1||m1>12) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Date 1");
    isValid = false;
}
...

if (isValid) {
    if(y1>y2)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Date1 > Date2");
    ...
}
```

Comment: wow, it works ... ti really can find a word to thank you 
thanks a lot dude ! :D

Answer (score 0):

This question needs alot of editing to  be more friendly, but your answer is pretty simple: the `else if` clause.

Let me explain:

When you get a value from the user, you want to **actually** do only one thing - show a message regarding the comparison of the two dates in hand.

But, in **some** cases, the value you got from the user is *invalid*. So, I would expect your code to look something like:

```
MyDateWrapper date = getDateEnteredByUser();
If(isDateValid(date)) {
// do something...
}
else {
//output error message...
}
```

This way, your conditions won't collide...
Hope I was clear enough. Good luck!